# Sql query regarding foreign key dependency

Tags: sql

I have two tables, Table A and Table B. Both the table have the "Id" column. Table B is dependent (foreign key) on this "Id". So i want to retrieve the rows which are not present in B.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: FK's are there to ensure data consistency. They are not needed to JOIN etc.

Answer (score 3):

You seems want :

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where not exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.id = a.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work in all flavours of SQL:

```
select t1.*
from TableA t1
left join TableB t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: I'd recommend having table aliases that make sense, like ta instead of t1 for TableA.

Comment: @jarlh While true, I doubt that the real underlying tables are called TableA and TableB

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE TableA
(
 ID INT,
 [Name] Varchar(500)
)
Insert INTO TableA Values(1, 'James')
Insert INTO TableA Values(2, 'John')
Insert INTO TableA Values(3, 'Betty')
Insert INTO TableA Values(4, 'Sherlin')

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
 TableBID INT,
 ID INT,
 Project Varchar(250)
)
Insert INTO TableB Values(1, 1, 'ABC')
Insert INTO TableB Values(2, 1, 'XYZ')
Insert INTO TableB Values(3, 2 , 'ASD')
Insert INTO TableB Values(4, 1, 'VGF')
Insert INTO TableB Values(5, 3, 'ABC')
Insert INTO TableB Values(6, 3, 'XYZ')
Insert INTO TableB Values(7, 2, 'FGH')

SELECT * FROM TableA a
WHERE  exists (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.id = a.id);
OR

SELECT * FROM TABLEA a WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TableB);

DROP TABLE TABLEA
DROP TABLE TABLEB